# Reading in csv file and converting to upper case in python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I'm trying to read in a csv file using the csv library.  I'm attempting to iterate through each line but convert to upper case before I attempt some useful function with each line.

```
import csv
reader = csv.DictReader(open('sample.csv', 'rb'))
for line in reader:
    line = line.upper()
    name = line['Name']
```

The above code doesn't appear to work.  It fails when I attempt to convert the line read in to upper.  I can change each column of the csv file read in to upper individually (using dictionary key) but I want to avoid that since there are lots of keys in the dictionary.

Comment: Could you post the error information as well?

Comment: you use a `csv.DictReader` object, which returns a `dict` as you iterate over it instead of a `tuple`, which is what `csv.reader` returns. Neither `dict` nor `tuple` has an `.upper` method. You probably want to call `.upper` on one of the contents of that `dict`.

Answer (score 2):

You can pre-process each line from the file object using a generator expression, before passing them to `csv.DictReader` which returns an iterable of dicts:

```
with open('sample.csv', 'rb') as f:
    header = next(f).strip().split(',')
    reader = csv.DictReader((l.upper() for l in f), fieldnames=header)
    for line in reader:
        name = line['Name']
```

---

Demo:

```
>>> f = ['a,b', 'c,d']
>>> c = csv.DictReader((l.upper() for l in f), fieldnames=('h1', 'h2'))
>>> list(c)
[{'h2': 'B', 'h1': 'A'}, {'h2': 'D', 'h1': 'C'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
import codes
txt = 'sampole.csv'
with codecs.open(txt, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    lines = [x.upper() for x in lines]
lines
```